# Can I jump to the ith iteration of a loop while debugging in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am debugging a C# program in Visual Studio. Consider the following snippet.

```
var List<string> cars = {"honda","bmw","ferrari","ford","jaguar"};
foreach (string car in cars){
    purchaseCar(car);
}
```

I wish to debug the *purchaseCar()* function when it is called for car="ford". However, while debugging in Visual Studio, I will have to *step over(F10)* the *purchaseCar()* function for previous three cars until I can finally *step into(F11)* it. This would be really tedious if there were a larger number of previous elements.

I wish to know if there is anyway I can directly jump to the ith iteration of a loop while debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: You can define conditions in break-point

Comment: Your `for` there is a `foreach` actually. You should use a `for` and just change the starting index and voila

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than thinking of it as "jumping to a particular iteration" I would suggest using a [*conditional break point*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#breakpoint-conditions).

Add the break-point in Visual Studio, e.g. on the `purchaseCar(car)` line, then right click on it and select "Conditions...". You can then set a condition, which in this case would be `car == "ford"`. Let the debugger run, and it will only break when the condition is true.